# Deep copies of IloObjective and IloRangeArray

Tags: c++, cplex

I have an environment and a model to create a linear programming model in c++.

```
IloEnv testenv;
IloModel testmodel(testenv);
```

I add the variables, objective function and constraints:

```
IloNumVarArray x = CreateNumVarArray(testenv);
IloObjective testobj = IloMaximize(testenv, IloSum(x));
testmodel.add(testobj);
IloRangeArray cnstr = CreateRangeArray(testenv);
testmodel.add(cnstr);
```

In order to create a deep copy of `testmodel`, I use the following piece of code:

```
IloModel testmodel1(testenv);
for (IloModel::Iterator it(testmodel); it.ok(); ++it)
    testmodel1.add(*it);
```

I can add new constraints to `testmodel1`, it does not affect the original model, `testmodel`.

```
IloRangeArray cnstr1 = CreateRangeArray; 
testmodel1.add(cnstr1);
```

However adding columns only to `testmodel1` is not possible:

```
IloNumColumn col(testenv);
col += testobj(int);
for (int i = 0; i < cnstr.getSize(); ++i) {
    col += cnstr[i](int);
}
IloNumVar newVar(col, 0, 1, ILOFLOAT);
testmodel1.add(newVar);
```

This is probably because I don't have copies of IloObjective and IloRangeArray. How can i create those copies? Or in general how can i add new columns to `testmodel1` without modifying `testmodel`?